# How to develop an an automator for looking up words in Google dictionary

Tags: automator, dictionary

If you type the following address in your browser's address bar, google will give you a dictionary for looking up words:

https://www.google.com/search?sa=X&biw=1440&bih=737&q=Dictionary#dobs=

If you add a new word like "hi" right after the equal sign at the end of the above link, it will give you a definition for it.

I am just thinking if I could make an apple automator app with an interface which asks for the new word, and retrieves the definition from the oxford dictionary presented by google. Any ideas how I might approach the above scenario? Is it possible to do it with Apple automator at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution A:** It's already built into macOS. Select any text using right click (ctrl) and Choose "Look up Hi".

[image: Look up feature]

[image: Oxford dictionary show up]

**Solution B:** If you are looking for a custom Automator workflow to set a search url, take a look at [codesnik answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/369934/mac-os-x-lion-chrome-shortcut-for-search-with-google/1246656#1246656)

[image]

**Solution C:** You can easily create your search hotkeys, using third party tool [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com)

Comment: You have that covered! nice options plus one...

Comment: @howdytom Thanks a lot for your answer. But that is not exactly what I need. Your second solution is close to what I need. But it only opens the webpage. What I really wanted to do through automator, if that was possible at all, was to enter the word, and receive the definition in the same environment. The automator, I hoped would retrieve the definition from the google dictionary and present to the user.

Comment: @developer: Possible, but you may have to add your preferred search string to the Automator Javascript code. Than, you have to export your Automator workflow as service. What you are looking can be easily created though Alfred's UI without custom code.

Comment: I really don't want to use a third-party app. I just want to accomplish this with automator. I have modified the second solution. First of all, I have added an "ask for text" action. Then the "Run JavaScript" and a "display Webpages" Action. And finally I saved it as an automator application. The problem now is that each time the automator app asks for an input and then displays the result in the webpage, it closes. Is there a way to keep the "ask for text" dialogue box open after it displays the result so that I can enter another word?

Comment: @developer: Yeah, once the Automator app has been executed, the workflow stops. In this case you would have to use a loop action. Take a look at utilities in Automator. Basically you need to save your current workflow as application. You can add your workflow by selecting your current workflow with "Run a workflow". Than add a loop action to restart your workflow which will trigger the "ask for text" field.